# Keeping text alignment and basic formatting when copy pasting from Excel to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

A client of mine uses a lot of tables from Excel in their WordPress site. And most of them are tables with a lot of numbers which should be aligned right for readability. They do the text alignment in Excel, but when it's pasted into WordPress the alignment goes away.

I could define text alignment in CSS, but there are also tables with some text content which should be aligned left.

I know you can change the text alignment in the TinyMCE editor, but since they already have defined this in their Excel documents they want to avoid doing double work with large tables in WordPress/TinyMCE.

Is there any way I can keep TinyMCE from stripping the text alignment when pasting into WordPress? Or are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The makers of TinyMCE have a paid plugin called PowerPaste - this has enhanced support for pasting from Word and Excel and an option to Keep Formatting.  If you Keep Formatting you should find that it will use inline styles to maintain that formatting.

You can test it (in general) here:  https://www.tinymce.com  (the demo editor at the top of the page has PowerPaste running).

If it solves your issue they do have a WordPress plugin for PowerPaste that would allow you to run this in Word Press pretty easily.

*(Disclaimer:  I work for the company that owns TinyMCE and PowerPaste)*

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work fine. With some CSS overrides I'll give that a go for now. Although the payment won't go through at your website at the moment. Please tell you manager ;-)